# Generic query and display system for JSON stored in a database

Tags: open-source, json, postgresql, django

I search a system which provides generic query and display of any JSON data.

Imagine I have stored this in a row of a database table:

```
{"foo": "bar", "foo2": "x"}
```

I want a text input field where I can search for "foo=bar" and as result I want to see above data (and all other rows which match the search term). I do not need other queries like Regex matches.

## My use case

A generic search interface for data created from structured logging.

## One (of many) way to solve this

Django ORM allows to query JSON stored in PostgreSQL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield

## Requirements

- open source
- it would be nice if Django and PostgreSQL could be used (no must)

Comment: @Thomas there are no files. There are db rows. But I could switch to a different DB, if it makes sense.

Comment: @Thomas up to now I need only exact matches, not regexs.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I made an edit to the question to include that. Comments might be deleted and I think that's relevant to be kept